# How can I reset the VS Code to normal code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I thought I have accidentally clicked some menus and the coding area was divided into 3 portions; Input 1, Input 2 and Result.
Can you please teach me how to bring coding area back to normal?
[image]
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS | VS Code source: Snap

Comment: what does the file look like when you `cat` or `less` it in the terminal, most likely you have a merge conflict

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a file name and select **Open With...**, VS Code gives 2 options of opening; **Text Editor** or **Merge Editor**. **Text Editor** is a normal plain page for writing codes.
[image]